# Mysql : Create trigger add two column value

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

Hello all i want to create a trigger to insert into a third column after adding 
two column. Here's the mysql

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER calcul_posts AFTER UPDATE
    ON table.test
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test 
('FinalPost') 
SELECT 
('New posts'-'excluded_posts') 
FROM  test
END;
```

I want to add value of Finalpost after sum 'New posts' - excluded_post

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to change the data in the same table, you want a "before update" trigger.  Then you just set the values:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER calcul_posts BEFORE UPDATE ON table.test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET FinalPost = `New Posts` - excluded_posts;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I assume the use of single quotes for the column names is a typo.

Comment: Error again : #1193 - Unknown system variable 'FinalPost'